# Installing xv6 on macOS

Tags: macos, xv6

I'm trying to install the xv6 OS on my macOS (version 10.14.3) following the instructions of [this site](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/tools.html), only with the newest versions of the needed files and when I'm getting at the binutils configuration stage I'm getting from my terminal:

> Config.guess failed to determine the host type.  You need to specify one.
>   Usage: configure [OPTIONS] [HOST]
>   Options: [defaults in brackets]
>    --prefix=MYDIR      install into MYDIR [/usr/local]
>    --exec-prefix=MYDIR     install host-dependent files into MYDIR[/usr/local]
>    --help          print this message [normal config]
>    --build=BUILD       configure for building on BUILD [BUILD=HOST]
>    --host=HOST         configure for HOST [determined via config.guess]
>    --norecursion       configure this directory only [recurse]
>    --program-prefix=FOO    prepend FOO to installed program names [""]
>    --program-suffix=FOO    append FOO to installed program names [""]
>    --program-transform-name=P transform installed names by sed pattern P [""]
>    --site=SITE         configure with site-specific makefile for SITE
>    --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [. or ..]
>    --target=TARGET     configure for TARGET [TARGET=HOST]
>    --tmpdir=TMPDIR     create temporary files in TMPDIR [/tmp]
>    --nfp           configure for software floating point [hard float]
>    --with-FOO, --with-FOO=BAR package FOO is available (parameter BAR)
>    --without-FOO       package FOO is NOT available
>    --enable-FOO, --enable-FOO=BAR include feature FOO (parameter BAR)
>    --disable-FOO       do not include feature FOO
>   Where HOST and TARGET are something like "sparc-sunos", "mips-sgi-irix5", etc.

What can I do to solve it? does anyone have better and validated instruction for installing xv6 on macOS? (I've also tried [this website](https://hzhuang.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/xv6-on-mac-os/) and it didn't work of course.)

Comment: Which exact command is failing? Did you try the steps at the top to check your existing compiler? Do you have Xcode and the command line tools installed?

Comment: @RetiredNinja `objdump -i` didn't work cause it didn't know what `-i` means. I dont have xCode installed but I do have the command line tool

Comment: `gcc -m32 -print-libgcc-file-name` prints `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.0/lib/darwin18.2.0/libclang_rt.builtins-i386.a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

all I needed to do is:

1. Install xCode and agree the terms of use.
2. Download xv6 from https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public.
3. Install MacPorts from https://www.macports.org/.
4. Open a terminal window where I downloaded the OS.
5. Install Qemu by writing `sudo port install qemu`.
6. `sudo port install i386-elf-gcc gdb`.
7. Replace the existing Makefile to a [new one](https://github.com/ashr123/XV6-MacOS-Makefile).
8. In order to run, write in the terminal window `make qemu clean`.

Comment: I'm also trying to build Xv6 on MacOS. The i386-elf-gcc toolchain can be installed easiy via Homebrew: https://github.com/nativeos/homebrew-i386-elf-toolchain. Using your Makefile, it chokes at `Makefile.osx:188: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.` (pointed to mkfs). Yes, mkfs can be easily compiled with Apple's gcc. Still stuck at that part, though.